# Ember.js - How to get current user properties in abilities source file while using ember-can addon

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-addon

How to get user object in abilities source file in [Ember-can](http://ember-can.com/) addon.
This is how my abilities file looks like.

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import { Ability } from 'ember-can';

export default Ability.extend({
    canWrite: Ember.computed('user.isAdmin', function() {
       return this.get('user.isAdmin');
    })
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [official documentation](http://ember-can.com/#injecting-the-user):

### Injecting the user

How does the ability know who's logged in? This depends on how you implement it in your app!

If you're using an `Ember.Service` as your session, you can just inject it into the ability:

```js
// app/abilities/foo.js
import Ember from 'ember';
import { Ability } from 'ember-can';

export default Ability.extend({
  session: Ember.inject.service()
});
```

If you're using ember-simple-auth, you'll probably want to inject the `simple-auth-session:main` session into the ability classes.

To do this, add an initializer like so:

```js
// app/initializers/inject-session-into-abilities.js
export default {
  name: 'inject-session-into-abilities',
  initialize(app) {
    app.inject('ability', 'session', 'simple-auth-session:main');
  }
};
```

The ability classes will now have access to session which can then be used to check if the user is logged in etc...

Comment: how can i get the user object via web service within the ability class?

Comment: I think that's something you actually shouldn't do to keep it DRY... Use a Service to get your user object via web service, and inject that service to your ability class.

Comment: How to inject that user object in ability class?

Comment: With DI provided by Ember: https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.10.0/applications/dependency-injection/#toc_ad-hoc-injections

Comment: You might want to give this series of screencasts a try, explaining in a lot more detail: https://www.emberscreencasts.com/tags/user-auth

Comment: Thanks for your help.finally i'm able to inject the user properties with session itself.but arise with another problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41825811/ember-js-how-to-pass-a-string-as-an-argument-in-ember-can-helper